# Python reading files // making new list

Tags: python

so basically, I have a text file with a list of words. I then have to create a raw input to let the user type in words and if the inputted word is in the text file, it will print "Right". for any word that isn't on that list, I have to put it in a different file with the number of "wrong" words.

For the most part, I have the user input correct, where if the word inputted is in the text file, it'll respond whether it is right or wrong.. but im having difficulty adding the wrong words into a different file.

```
print 'Opening file wordlist.txt'
b = open('wordlist.txt')

print 'Reading file wordlist.txt'
word_list = b.readlines().lower().split()
b.close()

in_word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
if in_word+'\n' in word_list:
print 'Right'



wrong_list = { word for word in in_word if word not in word_list}
return wrong_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do

```
wrong_list = []

print 'Opening file wordlist.txt'
b = open('wordlist.txt')

print 'Reading file wordlist.txt'
word_list = b.readlines().lower().split()
b.close()

in_word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
if in_word+'\n' in word_list:
    print 'Right'

else:
    wrong_list.extend(in_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'Opening file wordlist.txt'
b = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')

print 'Reading file wordlist.txt'
word_list = b.read().splitlines()

b.close()

c = open('wronglist.txt', 'r')
wrong_list = c.read().splitlines()
c.close()



in_word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
if in_word in word_list:
    print 'Right'
else:
    print 'Wrong'
    c = open('wronglist.txt', 'a')
    if in_word not in wrong_list:
        c.write("%s\n" % in_word)
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
in_word = ''
wrong_list = []

with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as f:
    word_list = f.read().lower().split()

while in_word is not '#':
    in_word = raw_input('Enter a word(type # to exit): ')

    if in_word is '#':
        break

    if in_word in word_list:
        print 'right'
    else:
        print 'wrong'
        wrong_list.append(in_word)

result = """Number of wrong words: %d
Wrong words: %s
""" % (len(wrong_list), ','.join(wrong_list))

print result

with open('wrong.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your current implementation is you need to know how to indent and how to use some features of python's if statement namely "else"

There is a great tutorial on this very relevant topic here.
https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html

You will also need to know how to open a file for writing.
explained here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open
which is simply:

```
with open('/path/filename_here.txt','w') as writeable_file:
    #do stuff here with the file
    writeable_file.write(line_to_write)
#the file is closed now.
```